# House Ads for SE questions can overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, markdown

It's possible for the ads that feature questions from the SE sites to overflow the box, causing the text to get cut off. For example, the ad for [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/does-pgflowlevel-pgftransformscale-do-the-same-as-normal-tikz-scale):

[image: Example of an overflowing ad]

Comment: I can't see what you're referring to... maybe a freehand circle would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The house ads no longer feature questions whose titles contain words with over 20 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be lacking the font that is referenced in the ad. What is your browser/OS?

Additionally, the title

> Does \pgflowlevel{\pgftransformscale{}} do the same as normal tikz scale?

has a long string of unbroken (no spaces) text. We'll have to see if the CSS style `word-wrap:break-word` helps in this situation.

Comment: Chromium 5.0.376.0 (p44230); Linux (Gentoo)

Comment: @Michael do you have the MS fonts installed? (I think you do by that screenshot.)

Comment: @radp I think so (I have [corefonts](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/) installed). I assumed it was the unbroken text problem Jeff mentioned in the second half of the answer